# Which moment does React import my JS file?

Tags: reactjs

In React, the imported JS code is read before rendering the HTML, right?

If I want to add an EventListener to an element, I'll always have to do it on the body (or document) load? Would I always need to create a function and attribute it to the `<body onLoad="fnOnLoad">` or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", "fnOnLoad", true);` ?

I'm asking this because if you use plain HTML and add the script in the end of the `<body>` section, It'll add the event to the element without me having to add it "on Load" of something, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like create-react-app, you only need to add event attribute to the element:

```
<Element onClick={//your code} />
```

or

```
<Element onChange={//your code} />
```

Check the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Comment: There's a reason why I asked about when my script will be imported. It would be too easy to attach the function like this, right? lol 
I´m dynamically creating a lot of this elements and they are all the same. I need the event listening for the code to know which element it must change. But thanks any way.

Comment: I think the js file is loaded after the html file, and then js will handle rendering the rest. Maybe you could clarify about your use case, what event you are trying to make and where do you want it to be attached ?

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount methods will do your tasks.

**componentDidMount**: When the component is mounted, add your DOM listener

**componentWillUnmount**: Make sure to remove the DOM listener when the component is unmounted

Following link might be Helpful for you.

https://linguinecode.com/post/react-onclick-event-vs-js-addeventlistener